# A verification from Gallian text

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Gallian **Ed.** 7 **Chapter** Group Homomorphism

[image]

I would like to verify the underlined calculation for $a=15:$

For chosen $x,y\in\mathbb Z_{12}$ we are to show that $30|15\times(x+_{12} y)-15 x-15y$

i.e. to show that $2|(x+_{12} y)-x-y$

By division algorithm $x+y=12q+r$ where $q\in\mathbb Z,0\le r<12$

Then $x+_{12}y=r$

So $2|-12q=r-x-y\implies 2|(x+_{12} y)-x-y$

Hence Proved.

Is my attempt correct?